# How can i customize permission for Attachment as well as Note object in my custom profile

Tags: customer-portal, profile

I have created custom profile which i am using for my customer portal users.How can i customize permission for Attachment and Note object?so that users can access attachment in customer portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place "Notes and Attachments" on the Page Layout for that Profile and it should just appear.

Answer (score 6):

Notes and Attachments are a little funky in that their aren't permissions associated with them directly.  Instead the permissions are determined based on the parent object which can cause [some issues](https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000Is5BEAS).  Specifically user's need to have Edit profile perms on the parent object and read/write visibility to the parent record.  In addition they'll need to have the "Notes and Attachments" related list visible on the page layout.

Comment: None of these really help, still same error. Whenever I try to access attachment on Community it gives me Insufficient error. Though we are able to query and fetch attachment record (ids), but unable to download/view attachments as it gives insufficient error.

Comment: @ChiragMehta sounds like that may be related, but since this is an old question I'd suggest asking another question with your specific download issue ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the object that contains Notes & Attachment is "Private" in OWD/Sharing settings. If "Grant access using hierarchy" is enabled then you can grant higher level of role to that user which resolve Insufficient Privilege error.