# Provide Access to User With Insufficient Privilege - Attachment?

Tags: profile, permissions, user

I have a scenario where a specific Custom profile users , they can see the notes and attachment section in the Order object. However when they click on the Attachment it shows them Insufficient privilege.

How can I provide them access?
I tried to find it by editing the profile but could not find.

Comment: See this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10339/how-can-i-customize-permission-for-attachment-as-well-as-note-object-in-my-custo which may help

Comment: @RobCowell it was not my question, My users can see the Notes and Attacment section, But when they click the attachment they get this message

Comment: Understood, but there's a comment on that question that relates to the underlying sharing model for attachments and how they relate to the parent object. May be worth a look.  Comment in question is at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11345/1027

Comment: It partially depends on how the attachment is actually stored. If it was uploaded in Lightning Experience, it's stored as a Salesforce file which can be shared w/o sharing access to the parent object. If it was uploaded in classic, there's a setting under Setup->Customize->Salesforce Files->Settings->General Settings to indicate if it's actually loaded as an Attachment object or as a Salesforce file (ContentVersion object)